# UnixODBC driver issues for .MDF databases. OR: is there a way to easily extract a bunch of tables without an sql server?

Tags: sql, linux, database, windows, perl

Disclaimer: I am somewhat of a n00b when it comes to database programming, so bear with me.

I've been attempting to batch process a rather large amount (~20 gb) of data all contained in .MDF SQL database files. The files contain meteorological data obtained through weather balloons, with each table consisting of ~1 second observations of winds, pressure, height, temps, etc, and are created with our radiosonde tracking software on an unnetworked Windows machine. It is possible (and quite easy) to load the files using the associated software and export the tables as an ASCII text file...however, this process involves manually loading each one. As I'm performing a study that requires as many soundings as possible (we have over 2000), doing this process over and over for several years of twice-daily observations is extremely time-prohibitive.

I've been taking the files off of the computer and putting them on my laptop running Linux Mint, and consider myself to be fluent with Perl...I do most of my data analysis with Perl scripts. That said, I've had the darndest time trying to get into the database files!

I've tried to connect to one of the files using the DBI package using variants on

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:$filename") or die "blahblahblah";
```

I have unixODBC installed and configured, have downloaded "libmyodbc.so" and "libodbcmyS.so", and keep getting the error

DBI connect('','',...) failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at dumpsql.pl line 6.

I've tried remedying this a number of ways over the past couple days, and I won't post them here for the sake of brevity. My odbcinst.ini file is as follows:

```
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/sib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

I'm seriously confused. I THINK I'm doing everything that various online tutorials are suggesting, but everyone else is connecting to servers and these files are all local and in the same directory! Could anyone attempt to point me in the right direction? All I want is to calculate meteorological values using vertical sounding data! Am I missing something totally obvious?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the original database server was a Microsoft SQL Server (MDF files). I am afraid these files alone are useless on a Linux machine. You need a Microsoft SQL Server on a Windows machine to get access to the contained data.

You described that you are able to attach a MDF file on a SQL server manually and then you can export the needed data as text files. Try to automate that. I'm not a MS SQL Server expert but it should be possible.

E.g. here is a [tutorial to attach and detach a MDF file via T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/24/sql-server-2005-t-sql-script-to-attach-and-detach-database/). So my approach would be to write a script which iterates over the 2000 MDF files and attach each to the SQL server. Then execute a query to export your data and then detach the MDF.

Comment: I know it's several months after the fact, but I eventually got it working: I wound up doing all the work using your method with PYODBC on my win7 partition. All of the data is extracted and I was able to finish my study! Thanks for the prompt answer, and sorry for the late feedback. I'd upvote but I lack the necessary reputation points. :)

Comment: Hey, nice to hear that you was successfull.